# CSS Float on anchor tag causes element to increase in size versus using it on a list item

Tags: html, css

With the following set up using `float` on an anchor  tag ,`a`, it causes the navigation to increase in size (versus using it on an `li` only - see below). Why is this?

```css
nav {
 background-color: rgb(25,25,25);
 border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
 border-left: none;
 border-right: none;
}
nav ul {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
nav li {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
}
nav a {
 float: left;
 font-size: .8em; 
 color: white;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 10px;
 border-right: 1px dashed rgba(255,255,255,.75);
 transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<nav class="clear">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">About The Book</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CSS Properties</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CSS Tips</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CSS Gotchas</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Versus using it on a list item as follows, the menu does not increase in height

```css
nav {
 background-color: rgb(25,25,25);
 border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
 border-left: none;
 border-right: none;
}
nav ul {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
nav li {
 float: left;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
}
nav a {
 font-size: .8em; 
 color: white;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 10px;
 border-right: 1px dashed rgba(255,255,255,.75);
 transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<nav class="clear">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">About The Book</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CSS Properties</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CSS Tips</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CSS Gotchas</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` is an inline element by default. Vertical padding on inline elements has no effect on layout — that is, it increases the click area of your `a` elements without affecting their line height (or the line height of its floating `li` element parent). But your `ul` has `overflow: hidden`, which clips the vertical padding on your `a` elements, meaning you never actually get to use this extra click area provided by the vertical padding.

Floating an inline box turns it into a block box, so the vertical padding now affects the layout of each `a` element, as you would expect with any block box (floating or not).

Answer (score 0):

That's because anchor tags (`<a>`) are initially `inline` elements, which aren't affected by paddings. Floating them causes them to behave in a somewhat different manner, a bit more like `inline-block`s (but not quite), which results in their padding being rendered to their box-models.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to work around this:

Apply `display: block` or `inline-block` to your `nav a`, to get the spacing to be like without using float.

```css
nav {
 background-color: rgb(25,25,25);
 border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
 border-left: none;
 border-right: none;
}
nav ul {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
nav li {
 float: left;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
}
nav a {
 font-size: .8em; 
 color: white;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 10px;
 border-right: 1px dashed rgba(255,255,255,.75);
 transition: all .5s;
        display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="clear">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">About The Book</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CSS Properties</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CSS Tips</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CSS Gotchas</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You can also just use display: block. Using display: list-item is pointless if you're not actually going to apply list styles to your elements, since display: list-item is essentially just display: block with a list style.

Comment: @BoltClock:  Correct.  I've realized that and have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that "anchor" tag is an inline element. The padding do not have any effect on inline elements. So when you write

```
padding=10px
```

it does not have any effect on the padding of the anchor tag.

BUT, all the inline elements act as block level elements when we use "float" property on them. So as soon as you write "float=left" for anchor tag, it starts working as a block level element. So, now padding came into effect. Means now the padding has effect on anchor tag, because it is not a block level element.

On the other hand, in the case of "li", you have not mentioned any padding. so it stays as it is, even with float=left.

I hope this is helpful.